# How to get associated product attribute text value in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, attributes

$ap_product is the associated product (simple product). Even though its a simple product, I can't use the method getResource(), because $ap_product is in catalog/product_type_configurable class. I know multiple ways to get the value of color attribute (ex: 255 stands for red) but I can't get the actual text "Red".

```
getResource()->getAttribute("color");

if($attribute->usesSource()){
$apColorSizeValue = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionValue($test);
}
```

Also this method would not work with, because its an associated product, not just a simple product.

```
 $_product->getAttributeText('color');
```

I've also tried to reload a product model but loading that associated product id. That didn't work either. So right now I have the associated product id and associated product attribute color value to work with. I need to get associated product attribute color text.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
$_associatedProduct = $ap_product->getId();
$_colorAttributeId = Color_ID
$query = "select cpei.value as id,eapv.value as value from catalog_product_entity_int cpei LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value eapv on cpei.value = eapv.option_id where cpei.entity_id=" . $_associatedProduct. " and cpei.attribute_id = " . $_colorAttributeId . " limit 1";
$color = $_readConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

Thank